# What shape do printers print?

Tags: printing, printer

So computer screens are made up of several tiny squares. What shapes do printers make? I mean, it would make sence that they make circles because of the way the ink spreads but then would it have printed the image you wanted or just something that looks like the image. What shape does a printer print? How does a printer print? What is the difference between a lazer printer and an ink printer?

Comment: This is really too broad, & starts with a false premise. Screen pixels aren't really square. Search Google Images for "screen pixels magnified" As for the rest, you're asking too many questions, each of which needs a huge amount of explanation. Please do some independent research first, then ask if you don't understand any one aspect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inkjets use droplets of ink that are absorbed by the paper.

> but then would it have printed the image you wanted or just something
> that looks like the image

I guess that depend on how literally you mean that.

Here's one of the biggest differences your screen is approx 100dpi, and even bad printers manage 300dpi.  Most printers are 600dpi or even 1200dpi, so the units are small enough you can't see the difference.

Similarly lasers use a powdered toner, and I doubt on a microscopic level that the toner is 100% uniform.  It is probably a variety of shapes, but when the pages and the toner go through the fuser at 300°F+ it is made flat and bonded with the page.  The specs are so tiny that any difference will never be noticed.

Generally the hardware uses DPI to form a uniform square grid, and 1 unit of ink is expected to fill one square.  If there is a tiny amount of over or under fill you won't notice it without a microscope.

---

Additional 3D printers start out with a round filament that goes through a round nozzle.  The filament is pressed against the surface compressing it into a line.  The very front of the line is round, but once it is smushed it forms a square spot.

Comment: I have written over 200 print drivers in my lifetime.  This is a very good answer.